# SQL Server: compare salary of people in the same table, and display both names, with the difference

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table:

[For Presenters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y51To.png)

and looking to get an output as follow:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdp1c.png)

I tried doing an inner join, but think got a bit confused as I'm still rather new with SQL

I got to display 2 names from the same table, but unsure where to place the comparison of the salary,

Here is my code where I tried:

```
select 
    t1.PNRFNAME, t2.PNRFNAME, t1.SALARY_YEARLY
from 
    PRESENTERS t1
inner join 
    PRESENTERS t2 on t1.PRESENTER_ID = t2.PRESENTER_ID
order by
    t1.SALARY_YEARLY DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a column called Salary_Diff:

```
select t1.PNRFNAME,t2.PNRFNAME, t1.SALARY_YEARLY, 

t1.SALARY_YEARLY - t2.SALARY_YEARLY AS Salary_Diff

from PRESENTERS t1
cross join PRESENTERS t2 
where t1.presenterid <> t2.presenterid
ORDER BY t1.SALARY_YEARLY DESC
```

Comment: Thanks helped a lot that I know now how to get the difference, any ideas on getting it to compare 2 of the rows with each other? Cause at the moment it would compare the same row with itself, so the salary_diff is still equal to 0

Comment: Just found a solution, by adding a != when comparing the rows, thanks for the help

Comment: @AdrianBeukes I have just updated my solution, which I used the cross join instead of join. Hope this time it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #PRESENTERS(PRESENTERID VARCHAR(20), PNRLNAME VARCHAR(25), PNRFNAME VARCHAR(25), AGE INT, YEAR INT , SALARY_YEARLY NUMERIC(11,2))

INSERT INTO #PRESENTERS

SELECT 'EMP_01','NEEDELL','TIFF',61,10,37451000.7            UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP_02','BUTLER-HENDERSON','VICKI',41,10,2426222.55  UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP_03','PLATO','JASON',45,8,2910000.98


;WITH A
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRESENTERID DESC) RN, *
FROM #PRESENTERS
)
SELECT A.PNRFNAME , A2.PNRFNAME, A.SALARY_YEARLY - A2.SALARY_YEARLY  SALARY_DIFF
FROM A
INNER JOIN A A2 ON A.RN < A2.RN
```