# SQL Server Finding the difference between rows

Tags: sql-server

I am still new at SQL Server and I need help with this question.

I need to produce an output like this:

```
PNRFNAME | PNRFNAME | Salary_Difference
---------+----------+------------------
Jason    | Vicki    |     483778.43
Jason    | Tiff     |  -34540999.72
Vicki    | Tiff     |  -35024778.15
```

The table that i currently have is filled with this data:

```
PresenterID | PnrLName         | PnrFName | age | years | Salary_Yearly
------------+------------------+----------+-----+-------+--------------
EMP_01      | NEEDELL          | Tiff     |  61 |   10  |  37451000.70
EMP_02      | BUTLER-HENDERSON | Vicki    |  41 |   10  |   2426222.55
EMP_03      | PLATO            | Jason    |  45 |    8  |   2910000.98
```

The code I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    a.Pnr_FName, b.Pnr_FName,
    CONCAT((a.Salary_Yearly - b.Salary_Yearly), (a.Salary_Yearly - a.Salary_Yearly)) AS Salary_Difference
FROM 
    PRESENTERS b
CROSS JOIN
    PRESENTERS a
```

Hope this makes sense! I tried to make my question clear

Comment: Research LEAD and LAG  if you want to compare a value to the previous or latter row if you have SQL 2012

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: compare salary of people in the same table, and display both names, with the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39129803/sql-server-compare-salary-of-people-in-the-same-table-and-display-both-names)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #PRESENTERS(PRESENTERID VARCHAR(20), PNRLNAME VARCHAR(25), PNRFNAME VARCHAR(25), AGE INT, YEAR INT , SALARY_YEARLY NUMERIC(11,2))

INSERT INTO #PRESENTERS

SELECT 'EMP_01','NEEDELL','TIFF',61,10,37451000.7            UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP_02','BUTLER-HENDERSON','VICKI',41,10,2426222.55  UNION ALL
SELECT 'EMP_03','PLATO','JASON',45,8,2910000.98

;WITH A
AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PRESENTERID DESC) RN, *
FROM #PRESENTERS
)
SELECT A.PNRFNAME , A2.PNRFNAME, A.SALARY_YEARLY - A2.SALARY_YEARLY  SALARY_DIFF
FROM A
INNER JOIN A A2 ON A.RN < A2.RN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lead or lag to get this: Use below query,

```
;with cte as (
select pnrfname, Salary_yearly, lag(salary_yearly) over (order by presenterid) lag_sal, 
lag(pnrfname) over (order by presenterid) as lag_fname from #PRESENTERS
) select pnrfname, lag_fname, salary_yearly-lag_sal from cte
```

Is this solves your requirement?